# Why does my service not stop when the app is terminated?

Tags: java, android, service, termination

I have a service in my app which adds a notification every few seconds.
My problem is that it doesn't stop when the app is stopped.
Can someone please let me know why is that?

My code:

Service class:

```java
public class ReminderService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                MyNotificationManager.postNotification(ReminderService.this, R.drawable.ic_back, "Return", "Return");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReminderService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
        startActivity(new Intent(this, PracticeActivity.class));
    }
}
```

My manifest:

```xml
<service android:name=".service.ReminderService"></service>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this, you can create a mechanism that stops the service when the application is stopped. Use a flag within the onDestroy() method of the **ReminderService** class to do this. This will stop the service when the application is stopped.

To get this result, you can make the following changes to your code:

```
public class ReminderService extends Service {

private boolean isStopped = false;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        while (!isStopped) {
            MyNotificationManager.postNotification(ReminderService.this, R.drawable.ic_back, "Return", "Return");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    isStopped = true;
} }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I meant why it's happening, because it shouldn't

Comment: Because of the inherent nature of a service created in this way, it will continue to run in the background even if the application is closed. Therefore, you should define a condition to terminate the operation when the application is closed rather than establishing an indefinite loop with while (true).

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that it doesn't stop when the app is stopped

I do not know how you are defining "the app is stopped".

I can tell you that you are leaking a thread. Once started, that thread will run until the process is terminated. Exactly *when* the process will be terminated is a complex subject.

If that is not your desired behavior, you need to stop that thread at some point. Given your existing code, [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74912766/115145) gives you a solution for that. Or, switch to something like `ScheduledExecutorService` instead of `Thread.sleep()`.